# Groups - identity - abstract algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite cyclic group with $n$ elements, $$G = \{a_1 , a_2,\dots,a_n\}$$
Let $x = a_1 \cdot a_2 \cdot \dots \cdot a_n$

1) Show that $x^2 = e$, where e is the identity of group $G$.

2) If we say that $n$ is an odd number, what is the order of $x$ ?

I'm realy stuck here, can someone help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. $G$ is abelian, hence we can rearrange the $a_i$ so that we can pair off elements with their inverses. The only ones that cannot be paired off are those which are their own inverses, that is $e$ and possibly one other element. Thus $x$ is either $e$ or the one nontrivial self-inverse element. At any rate the square is $e$.
2. There must be an odd number of self-inverse elements then and hence $e$ is the only one. Which makes $x=e$

Comment: For (1) it's easier to pair $a$ in one 'copy' of $x$ with $a^{-1}$ in the other 'copy' of $x$.

Answer (score 1):

1) Suppose $G = <g> $, so ord($g$) $ = n $. A cyclic group is abelian so $$x = a_1 \cdot a_2 \cdot \dots \cdot a_n = g^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}} \Rightarrow x^2 = g^{n(n-1)} = 1$$

2) If $n$ is odd $m = \frac{n-1}{2} \in \mathbb{N}$ and so $$x = g^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}} = (g^{n})^m = 1$$